# How to use FindWindow() to get child class with same name

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

Need help to get the child class HWND and to control and send text to it , the problem is that all the children class are with the same name.
here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "handles.h"
FILE *fptr;
int brackets;
char line[100];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD procId;
    HWND mainEdit,MsgViewer,MDIClient,perant,hApp=FindWindow(TEXT("SWT_Window0"),NULL); 
    HANDLE hProc;;

    if(hApp==NULL)
    {
        WinExec("C:\\Users\\Mugtaba\\Desktop\\eclipse\\haha.exe",SW_SHOW);
        Sleep(1800);    
    }   

hApp=FindWindow(TEXT("SWT_Window0"),NULL);
perant=hApp;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hApp, &procId);

}
```

i have used spy++ and here is picture for what it looks like [spy++ screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBPS4.png)
any work around and sample code will be helpful.

Comment: These child windows appear to have a valid ID, that makes GetDlgItem() work.

Comment: Yes,,But how to reach  that ID while they change every restart ?